# Variable is assigned but its value is never used

Tags: c#

The code:

```
int num01;
num01 = 20;
```

Gives:

> Warning CS0219 The variable 'num01' is assigned but its value is never used

Comment: You shouldn't need to add a picture. We don't like pictures of code. Pictures of error messages are sometimes helpful, but the raw text of the error message should always be included in your question as well (not as a pic). Also - you never actually asked a question. Please ask a clear question so we know which part you need clarification on.

Comment: This is just a warning, so it shouldn't stop you from running your application (so long as you haven't set it treat warnings as errors)

Answer (score 5):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0219

You're creating a variable named `num01`, but you're not using it. I'm far from a C# expert, but I assume the easiest way to get rid of this warning would be to either use or remove the offending variable.

Comment: This happens often in the IDE when you're developing code. Just ignore it when you plan to use the variable later on. But if it stays there longer - you've written some code that needs improvement.

Comment: A slight addition to this answer: The warning usually only shows for private properties or variables. Most times I get it, it is because I messed up the access modifier (e.g. private, public, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning, not an error. Everything will still compile and run fine.

Assigning a value to a variable is not 'using' it.

Although not recommended, you can suppress this warning by adding the following line above it

```
#pragma warning disable CS0219
```

Answer (score 0):

[CS0219](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0219) is a warning, not an error, so your program should compile. It might seem strange to you, because you are "using" the variable by assigning 20 to it. The warning message should be understood as pointing out that you are not using the variable in any other way *besides* assigning to it. In other words, the assignment cannot have any effect, other than if you are stepping through the program and looking at values in the debugger. If you add another line to your code using the variable in any way other than an assignment, then the warning will go away. For example, the following will do:

```
    int num01;
    num01 = 20;
    Console.WriteLine(num01);
```